# Installed, just not linked

Tags: macos, homebrew

Note: I'm not so good at using shell.

I was trying to install `Valgrind` using `brew` on Yosemite.

`brew install --HEAD valgrind`

Towards the end, I got an error having to do with linking so when I tried to reinstall, I got:

> Warning: valgrind-HEAD already installed, it's just not linked

So apparently I've already installed it. Then based on other SO questions and answers, I tried:

`brew link valgrind`

This seemed to solve other people's problems with linking an already installed software but this gave me an error:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD... 
Error: Could not symlink lib/pkgconfig/valgrind.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig is not writable.
```

I also tried to update `brew` but it didn't solve the issue. If it is not writable, maybe `sudo` would give me permission but I don't want to use `sudo` without knowing exactly what I am doing.

What is happening and how to I fix it?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Looks like a permission issue. I would try doing this

```
chmod 755 /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

This should make that available, then try

```
brew link valgrind
```

If that doesn't work I would try doing a check on it

```
brew doctor
```

Comment: I use `brew doctor`, and by the instructions, then use `chown` twice to solve the problem.

Comment: @yanzi1225627 why twice?

Answer (score 34):

First run

```
brew link <package>
```

If it gives an error, try for an automated diagnosis

```
brew doctor
```

`brew doctor` gives a list of problems that could be leading to errors in installation process.

To fix problems in case of conflicting files, 
run to get a list of all actions which **will be performed** by overwrite without actually performing them.

To list all files that would be deleted:

```
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run <package>
```

followed by this run which will execute the overwrite, assuming you feel that the actions performed by overwrite will take your system to a more **stable state**.

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:

```
 brew link --overwrite <package>
```

Answer (score 14):

If none of above the solution works, try this.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local
brew link <package-name>
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, **brew doctor** got it right. At some point /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig was set to be owned by **root** rather than my account. The prescribed remedy worked -

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and i resolved with next solution: 
Run **brew doctor** from Terminal to check all your errors

then run next command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/etc /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share
```

after run:

```
brew link <package_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I tried and it worked:

```
$ brew link --overwrite sdl
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/sdl/1.2.15...
Error: Could not symlink lib/pkgconfig/sdl.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig is not writable.
```

Looked for `pkgconfig`: (after `chmod 750`)

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 root           wheel   136B Mar 30  2013 pkgconfig
```

I tried `chown` as below:

```
$ sudo chown -R  avkashchauhan:admin /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

it should look like as below:

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 avkashchauhan  admin   136B Mar 30  2013 pkgconfig
```

After I tried it:

```
$ brew link sdl                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/sdl/1.2.15... 182 symlinks created
```

Answer (score 1):

Type

`link valgrind`

It will show an error that it can't be linked because such-and-such directory is not writable. Cool, we make it writable now. Type

`sudo chmod a+w the/directory/shown/as/error`

If the directory is not writable, you wont be able to change its permission and make it writable either. Sudo will make this operation possible. chmod will change the mode and will make all(a) users be able to write(w) it.

Next you will be prompted to type your system's password. After this, again type

`link valgrind`

and it will work this time.

Answer (score 1):

```
brew install cocoapods --build-from-source
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

The only commands that worked for me on after upgrading to MAC OS Mojave 10.14.6

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem,

$ brew install sqlite
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
No changes to formulae.

Warning: sqlite-3.17.0 already installed, it's just not linked.

I tried to link it,

$ brew link sqlite
Warning: sqlite is keg-only and must be linked with --force
Note that doing so can interfere with building software.

Then do it by force,

$ brew link --force sqlite
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.17.0... 8 symlinks created

Answer (score 0):

I had same a problem about permission, but after I give my permission, still error permission. And here I do, first:

```
brew unlink valgrind
```

and then,

```
brew link valgrind
```

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. I needed to `brew link carthage`.
But none of answers worked for me.

I've also seen the next error for any command I tried:

```
Error: Could not symlink .
/usr/local/opt is not writable
```

Only one solution helped:

1. Open the Finder;
2. `Command` + `Shift` + `G`;
3. Pass the `/usr/local` path;
4. Create `opt` folder manually (that was the folder name from my error message, but in your case it can be something different, such as `lib/pkgconfig` in the original question, so check yours in the `Terminal`);
5. re-run your command again.