# msgmerge on macos Catalina

Tags: macos, gettext, macos-catalina, msgmerge

I am trying to run a unix command line for some i18n work on a project. Using **gettext library** my issue is about running [`msgmerge`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/msgmerge-Invocation.html)

```
$ msgmerge
zsh: command not found: msgmerge
```

I tried `brew instal gettext` and `brew link gettext` but with no success. This was working well on my previous machine, but can't make it work on a fresh install.

I can confirm binary is available in `/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin/msgmerge`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed. When running `brew reinstall gettext`, command actually give the answer:

```
If you need to have gettext first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Export is only triggered when opening a new zsh prompt, PATH was not updated yet and worked when I re-openned a new window.

Answer (score 1):

I tried running this `brew link gettext --force`, but I was getting:

```
$ brew install gettext
Warning: gettext 0.20.2 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 0.20.2, run `brew reinstall gettext`

$ brew link gettext --force
Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: gettext
If you need to have gettext first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find gettext you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include"
```

Then, I just added it to the system path with:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Related:

1. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299048/can-not-use-the-gettext-which-is-installed-by-brew
2. [Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670295/homebrew-refusing-to-link-openssl)
3. [How to install gettext on MacOS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940383/how-to-install-gettext-on-macos-x)
4. [Installed, just not linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29422345/installed-just-not-linked)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution 