# ansible not install perfectly using "brew install ansible" command not work in MacOS ? error: -sh: /usr/local/bin/ansible: No such file or directory

Tags: python, macos, ansible, homebrew

I've tried to install Python with the terminal (`brew`) as well as using `.dmg` package.

```
command: brew install python
and this path is python when install using dmg
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
```

But I'm getting the error listed below.

[image]

After that I tried `ansible` install:

```
brew install ansible
```

and `which ansible`
[image]

Last ansible command ping for all or host :
[image]

Is it an OS-specific issue or something else? Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

### If `brew`, then check your `brew` version...

If you really need `brew install`, check updates.
There is a [known issue #5021](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/5021) on macOS 10.13.6. And [#5019](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/5019) fixes it.

### ... but I'd suggest to use `pip install`

Since `ansible` depends on `python`, I'd highly recommend to use common way of installing `python` apps:

```
pip3 install ansible
```

Or, from repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/ansible/ansible.git
cd ansible
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
python3 setup.py install
```

## `brew` warning

Warning from screenshot says:

> ansible is already installed, it's just not linked

So, you might [try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29422345/installed-just-not-linked):

```
brew unlink ansible
sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/etc /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share
brew link  --overwrite ansible
```

If it doesn't help:

```
brew doctor
```